# starting a new session automatically when a user changes the session variable i.e. changes there email address

Tags: php

the session variable on my website is the users email address and there is an option for the user to change there email address, at the moment, when they change there email address the session variable is obviosly automatically destroyed so they have to log in again with the new address, I would like a way to automatically change the session variable to the new email address. is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You literally just redefine it as the new value.

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $newEmailAddressVariable;
```

Answer (score 0):

The session should not be destroyed when the user changes their email address unless you're explicitly destroying it with `session_destroy()`.  Either way, you could take what's currently in $_SESSION before the change and assign it to the existing or a new session after the email address change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the email address to reference the user currently logged in?

I would suggest you to use an never-changing ID like a auto-increment-id from an database. This is a more robust way...